# todays date and future date dropdown list in a ComboBox

Tags: vba, excel

every time i start up the file and click the macro for the userform, the combobox should have the list of dates from today and future dates, it can not have past dates.

this is the code that I have, it only inputs the date in the combobox and formats the value of the list. but i don't know how to list down the future dates in it.

```
Public Sub UserForm_initialize()
    ComboBox3.Value = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    ComboBox3.Value = Format(ComboBox3.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Date` use `Now()`.  "Date" is a semi-reserved keyword for a data type. You may be able to get away with using it as a variable, but it would be ambiguous/confusing to do so.

The way I would do this is to use the listbox `.AddItem` method in a loop, with some date arithmetic, using the `DateAdd` function (super handy, if you work with dates a lot!).

```
Public Sub UserForm_initialize()
    Dim i as Integer
    Dim myDate as Date
    myDate = Now()
    For i = 0 to 10 'Add the next 10 days, for example
        ComboBox3.AddItem Format(DateAdd("d", i, myDate), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    Next
    ComboBox3.ListIndex = 0 
End Sub
```